# Sum of complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I wish to prove that all the roots of polynomials of the form:

$$P(z)=1+2z+3z^2+...+nz^{n-1}$$

are confined within a circle $|z|<1$.

Here is what I did so far:

I multiplied $P(z)$ with $\frac{1-z}{1-z}$, so:

$\frac{1-z}{1-z}P(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{k=1}^n (kz^{k-1}-kz^k)=\sum_{k=1}^n k(z^{k-1}-z^k)$

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: This is a direct consequence of [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem).

Comment: Do you mean **the roots** of the polynomial are in the disk $\;|z|<1\;$ ? Is that what "confined" mean here?

Comment: @DonAntonio I feel so dumb now, I missed that part. thanks.

Comment: Your idea can also be taken to term. Instead of multiplying and dividing by $1-z$, do so but with $(1-z)^2$. The numerator will cancel except for three terms. Then you can apply Rouche's theorem to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

$$T(z)=z+z^2+z^3+\ldots+z^n=z\left(1+z+\ldots+z^{n-1}\right)=z\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}$$

So all the zeros of $\;T(z)\;$ are within $\;|z|\le1\;$ . Now calculate $\;T'(z)\;$ and apply Gauss-Lucas Theorem...